# share access-token between server part of app and client part of app

Tags: facebook, oauth

I just joined a project where android client uses facebook connect to authenticate the user and/or do some actions on facebook. but our server also needs to connect to facebook. this is done by first sending the access-token (from OAuth) to the server. both the client and server share the OAuth credentials so they both can use the same access-token.

something feels utterly wrong by this approach. anyone can think of any traps with that approach ?

Comment: I don't think of any. This is quite a common practice, and used by us a lot. The only issue you need to concern is to keep the token synced between server and client, for example, if it is outdated, invoked, etc.